# Obtain PubMed info from PMIDs using RefManageR - in a loop

Tags: r, loops, pubmed

I am trying to retrieve citation info from PubMed -using RefManageR and PubMed IDs (pmids)-.

I chose RefManageR because it's really easy to paste the output in a data.frame format. And for me is still difficult to understand and use the PubMed API on my own.

I was able to write code that uses a "string of PMIds" as input to get the data:

```
require(RCurl)
urli <- getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aurora-mareviv/3840512f6777d5293218/raw/dfd6b76ceb22c52aa073fc05211dcea986406914/pmids.csv", ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)
pmids <- read.csv(textConnection(urli))
head(pmids)
index10 <- pmids$pmId[1:10]
indice10 <- paste(pmids$pmId[1:10], collapse=" ")

# install.packages("RefManageR")
library(RefManageR)
auth.pm10 <- ReadPubMed(indice10, database = "PubMed", mindate = 1950)
auth.pm10d <- data.frame(auth.pm10)
View(auth.pm10)
```

However, if I want to get citations from 500 pmids, I think I should avoid a long query in the PubMed server. My idea would be to make a function that loops through all the elements in the vector `index10`, similar to this:

```
extract.pub <-
  function(id=indice, dbase=d.base, mindat=1950){
    require(RefManageR)
    indice <- id # Author
    d.base <- dbase # like PubMed, etc
    min.dat <- mindat # Date from...
    auth.pm <- NULL
    for(i in indice){
      auth.pm <-  ReadPubMed(indice, database = d.base, mindate = min.dat)
      }
    auth.pm <- data.frame(auth.pm)
    auth.pm
   }

cites <- extract.pub(index10, dbase="PubMed")
View(cites)
```

It gives the following error: `Error : Internal server error`.

However, if I insert `indice10` (string) instead of `index10` (vector), it works:

```
cites <- extract.pub(indice10, dbase="PubMed")
View(cites)
```

¿How could I make this loop work? or maybe this approach is not the best for my purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReadPubMEd` only accepts one pmid or query per function call. Try:

```
lapply(pmids[1:3], ReadPubMed, database = "PubMed", mindate = 1950)
```

gives

```
[[1]]
[1] P. M. Zeltzer, B. Bodey, A. Marlin, et al. “Immunophenotype profile of childhood
medulloblastomas and supratentorial primitive neuroectodermal tumors using 16 monoclonal
antibodies”. Eng. In: _Cancer_ 66.2 (1990), pp. 273-83. PMID: 2196109.

[[2]]
[1] L. C. Rome, R. P. Funke and R. M. Alexander. “The influence of temperature on muscle
velocity and sustained performance in swimming carp”. Eng. In: _The Journal of
experimental biology_ 154 (1990), pp. 163-78. PMID: 2277258.

[[3]]
[1] P. Henry. “[Headache, facial neuralgia. Diagnostic orientation and management]”. Fre.
In: _La Revue du praticien_ 40.7 (1990), pp. 677-81. PMID: 2326596.
```

You can put elements of the `BibEntry` class into a data.frame and format authoring nicely

```
lapply(pmids[1:3], function(x){
 tmp <- unlist(ReadPubMed(x, database = "PubMed", mindate = 1950))
 tmp <- lapply(tmp, function(z) if(is(z, "person")) paste0(z, collapse = ",") else z)
 data.frame(tmp, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
})
```

gives

```
                                                                                                                                    title
1 Immunophenotype profile of childhood medulloblastomas and supratentorial primitive neuroectodermal tumors using 16 monoclonal antibodies
2                                               The influence of temperature on muscle velocity and sustained performance in swimming carp
3                                                                      [Headache, facial neuralgia. Diagnostic orientation and management]
                                   author year                             journal volume number  pages  eprint language eprinttype bibtype
1 P M Zeltzer,B Bodey,A Marlin,J Kemshead 1990                              Cancer     66      2 273-83 2196109      eng     pubmed Article
2        L C Rome,R P Funke,R M Alexander 1990 The Journal of experimental biology    154   <NA> 163-78 2277258      eng     pubmed Article
3                                 P Henry 1990               La Revue du praticien     40      7 677-81 2326596      fre     pubmed Article
     dateobj                        key
1 1990-01-01 zeltzer1990immunophenotype
2 1990-01-01          rome1990influence
3 1990-01-01          henry1990headache
```

Comment: Thanks , I hadn't thought of apply! However, I've been trying to modify your code to obtain something that can be coerced to data.frame. For example:
`adata <- ddply(pmids[1:3], "pmId", ReadPubMed, database = "PubMed", mindate = 1950)` 
and the same error again. I think I don't catch important concepts here about apply..

Comment: Well, the return from `ReadPubMed` is of class `BibEntry`, which in reality is a list o about 13 elements. So you could make each one of those elements a column in a data.frame if you want. You can't, as far as I know, bput the BibEntry class object into a data.frame. I'll edit answer above